# How to show all the search items from the android database

Tags: android, database, search

I am making an android app that needs to query data item from its database. I'm almost done. But it shows only one item when I search an item, although there are more items to display( i.e, there are more than one item that matches with the searching value.
my code for searching is here...

```
 search_group.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            et_group = ET_GROUP.getText().toString();
            et_district = ET_DISTRICT.getText().toString();
            et_city = ET_CITY.getText().toString();
            DatabaseOperations DOP = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
            Cursor CR = DOP.getInformation_Search(DOP);
            CR.moveToFirst();
            boolean login_status = false;
            String NAME = "";
            String PHONE_NUM = "";
            String DISTRICT = "";
            String CITY = "";
            String GROUP = "";

            do {

                NAME = CR.getString(0);
                DISTRICT = CR.getString(1);
                CITY = CR.getString(2);
                GROUP = CR.getString(3);
                PHONE_NUM = CR.getString(4);


                if (et_group.equals(CR.getString(3))&& et_district.equals(CR.getString(1)) ) {
                    login_status = true;

                    for (CR.moveToFirst(); !CR.isAfterLast(); CR.moveToNext())
                    {
                        show_result.setText("found\n" + "Group = " + GROUP + "\n Name = " + NAME + "\nDistrict = " + DISTRICT + "\nCity = " + CITY + "\nPhone Number = " + PHONE_NUM);
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    show_result.setText("Group not FOUND !!");
                }


            } while (CR.moveToNext());
```

I've declared ,

```
 TextView show_result;
show_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_search_blood_group);
```

and the .xml code is

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_search_blood_group"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already moving to the last in the internal for loop here:

```
for (CR.moveToFirst(); !CR.isAfterLast(); CR.moveToNext())
                    {
                        show_result.setText("found\n" + "Group = " + GROUP + "\n Name = " + NAME + "\nDistrict = " + DISTRICT + "\nCity = " + CITY + "\nPhone Number = " + PHONE_NUM);
                    }
```

Either use another cursor or rememember the position and move back.

**Update after your comment**

After all the discussion in comments the final code should be this:

```
search_group.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            et_group = ET_GROUP.getText().toString();
            et_district = ET_DISTRICT.getText().toString();
            et_city = ET_CITY.getText().toString();
            DatabaseOperations DOP = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
            Cursor CR = DOP.getInformation_Search(DOP);
            CR.moveToFirst();
            boolean login_status = false;
            String NAME = "";
            String PHONE_NUM = "";
            String DISTRICT = "";
            String CITY = "";
            String GROUP = "";

            do {

                NAME = CR.getString(0);
                DISTRICT = CR.getString(1);
                CITY = CR.getString(2);
                GROUP = CR.getString(3);
                PHONE_NUM = CR.getString(4);


                if (et_group.equals(CR.getString(3))&& et_district.equals(CR.getString(1)) ) {
                    login_status = true;
                    show_result.setText(show_result.getText() + "found\n" + "Group = " + GROUP + "\n Name = " + NAME + "\nDistrict = " + DISTRICT + "\nCity = " + CITY + "\nPhone Number = " + PHONE_NUM);
                }

                else
                {
                    show_result.setText(show_result.getText() +  "Group not FOUND !!");
                }


            } while (CR.moveToNext());
```

Comment: But I think the internal loop should print or show the matched items from first to last, isn't it??

Comment: no. you are initializing the printed variables outside the loop. I'll post and update to the answer in a minute. hold on

Comment: I've copied and paste your answer, but this time also it is showing the last matched value rather then showing all. Is it the reason that I am using a TextView under a scroll view ? or anything ???

Comment: oh! you are replacing it... try appending

Comment: I've tried to your updated for loop replacing my for loop , and the problem is remaining.

Comment: did you add `show_result.getText() + ` inside set text?

Comment: Oh , Sorry, I missed that. But this time it is showing all the data from the database rather than showing the matched items...

Comment: because the comparison is happening outside for loop. Now you are getting all values it is just about figuring out the loop and placement of condition checks. move the if condition inside the for loop and you probably do not need the external do..while now

Comment: or remove the for loop and let do...while do the looping

Comment: updated answer again.. i think you can just pick up this one and use.

Comment: I've put the if else condition inside the for loop . this time it works exactly when I'm not using the else condition that is that time when the group is not found. But when the else is used it is showing only not found i.e executing the else condition and the if condition is not working , that is no matched data is showing.

Comment: I've copied and paste your updated answer but the problem is that it is showing not found although there are matched items that means executing the else condition rather than if

Comment: when else is not used it is working good but nothing is showing when there is no matched items\]

Comment: add `show_result.getText() + ` in setText inside else also

Comment: I've added show_result.getText() + in setText inside else also but this time it is showing not found for unmatches and showing the matched items also. that means there are so many "Group Not Found" inside the matched items.

Comment: yes, now you need to decide what you want to print and what not. Cant help with that. :)

Comment: you may not have understand my problem , it is showing not found not found then when it got the matched item then it is showing the value when  unmatched then not found again. But if I dont use the else condition then it works exactly, but this time the only problem is that it will not show not found if there is no matched items...

Comment: what exactly do you want to print? if multiple not found print not found just once?

Comment: I want that when not data is found then it will show "Group Not Found", But when found then only show the data , But this time it is showing the data as well as "group Not Found"

Comment: lol ... that is because you dont have `\n` before your string `"Group not FOUND !!"` ... change it to `\n\n"Group not FOUND !!"`. That not found is for the next item in your cursor.

Comment: just out of curiosity I'd like to ask: Since when are you coding (in general, not just android) ?

Comment: No , I've solved it, declaring a counter .If I use else condition inside the loop the loop then it will surely show data if matched or not found if unmatched with the database value. Now I've declared a counter variable and initialized as zero , and when there is matched data the counter variable increases otherwise it remains the same . then in the outside loop I tested if it is still zero . if it is then "group Not Found"  and now it is working perfectly for me . Anyway thank you for helping me solving this problem...

Comment: awesome... finally :) was a good exercise for my brain today... nice to hear you got it working in the end.

Comment: surely I'll mark the answer as it helped me most, but astonished to see that you could not understand the simple thing as the else condition will work for all the time the loop will run, so it should not be inside the loop . Anyway , don't mind and Thank U :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are replacing values on show_result TextView. Concat your Cursor string values and add it once on show_result.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
show_result.setText("text here");
```

use

```
show_result.append("text here");
```

You are doing right, but anytime the condition is true. It sets new text to textview and replace the previous one. That's why in the end, there is only one value shown in the textview. So you can use

```
textView.append()
```

it appends new value to previous one. Hope it's work